# Solving a system of equations with more than 2 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I having trouble solving this system of equations. It would be easy if every equation used every variable, but that's not the case. Instead, the system is:

$$\begin{cases}a + b + c = 14 \\ d + f + g = 16 \\ c + a + f = 8 \\ g + b + h = 24 \\ a + d + c + g = 22 \\ b + f = 8 \\g + a + b = 18 \\c + f + h = 11\end{cases}$$

I have been trying to figure this out for several days, but I can't  seem to figure it out. Any help at all?

Comment: Computer says: This system has no solution.

Comment: @John_Lou thank you! I was able to get it from that. Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as answered please?

Comment: Why do you think it would be easier if every equation used every variable? That would to the contrary make it quite a bit harder. The technique of Gaussian elimination actually amounts to trying to _remove_ certain variables from some equations by forming appropriate combinations of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$b+f=8 = c+a+f$$
$$a+c=b, a+b+c=2b=14, b=7$$ 
And you can solve quickly from there. In general, you can still solve in a similar way by setting two equations equal to each other or subtracting to remove a variable.

Answer (score 0):

$b+f=c+a+f=8,$ so $a+b+c=2b=14$, so $b=7$. In turn, $f=8-b=1$.

Now, $g+h=24-7=17$. From the last two equations,

$$\begin{align}\underbrace{a+b+c}_{14}+\underbrace{g+h}_{17}+\underbrace{f}_1&=18+11=29 \\ \end{align}$$ 
However, $14+17+1\neq29$, so we have a contradiction.

Therefore, the system has no solution.